# Firebase child fails, path exists

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to reference a location in my Firebase database, but `.child()` fails with the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "https://wooperate.firebaseio.com/comments-to/-KTLOwq-WK4VwMhG7Zz8/-KTPmJJtmZQa7ldWILks". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Not only is it a valid path, but it also contains data!

Am I thick or is this just a bug in Firebase?

---

**Edit:** This is the code that triggers the error:

```
FIREBASE_REF.child('comments-to').child(post.id).child(comment.id);
```

Explanation of variables:

- FIREBASE_REF: root referance to my firebase database
- post.id: Firebase generated id
- comment.id: <del>Firebase generated id</del> **Full Firebase reference to the comment** ― This was the error :(

The following does *not* trigger any errors:

```
FIREBASE_REF.child('comments-to').child(post.id);
```

As stated above, the path to the comment exists and contains data.

Comment: Show the [minimal code that triggers the error](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: have you logged `comment.id` to ensure it's what you expect?

Comment: @mjr Yes, and the error message contains the correct comment id in the path that is supposedly invalid.

Comment: I'm really sorry @mjr, it really was the `comment.id` just like you suspected.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `comment.id` is empty or contains `".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"` as said in logcat. Sometimes using `-` and nodes starting with Capital Letter also cause this problem. It could be with `comments-to` try using `commentsTo` instead.

Comment: I've tried changing it (both in fontend and in Firebase) from `comment-id` to `commentId`, but it made no difference. Also, if you look at the error message, there are no invalid characters in the path.

Answer (score 0):

*Yes*, I'm thick.

I misunderstood the error message. Of course the illegal argument was the argument provided to `child()`: i.e. `comment.id`, and not the (url to) the reference resulting from the call `.child(comment.id)`.

The source of the error was that I used `snap.ref` rather than `snap.val` when I set the `comment.id`.